# Installing a free world-compatible SSL certificate in WHM/Cpanel

Tags: google, https, security-certificate, http

It's been a while but here I am again.

I just found out today that users of chrome 69 or later will see a big "insecure" message for webpages beginning with http:// such as mine and even Bing's search engine.

So I thought I need to please Donald Trump. Sorry, but I mean we're getting into internet politics here when my site is purely a site in which no security is required to browse the content. --end rant--

The point is, I also want to create an HTTPS version (just to please people) of the site except I'm new with certificates.

From what I gathered, I have to create a certificate, then submit it to an authority to get approval then attach it to my apache configuration and restart apache so the certificate is transferred to the user's browser the first time the site is requested.

My cpanel gives me an option to buy a certificate from trustwave, but I'd rather use a free certificate and I do not see that option.

I also plan to use crontab to automatically run a command to update my certificates automatically to keep the HTTPS site running.

Now an article on Google told me the first steps to creating a key in shell which I have done already. I read: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/enable-https?hl=en

But I need to know the rest of the process.

Could I just go to some URL of the authority I want to submit my key to? (example: http://www.whatever.com/submitkey?keyfile=example.com.key) and wait for approval by email then somehow apply that key into cpanel once approved?

I'm trying to understand the whole process so I can spend like 5 minutes doing configuration work so that I can then load any page in HTTPS when the HTTPS version of the site is setup.

Comment: In cPanel this is a relatively new function called AutoSSL that you can configure to work with your certificate issuer of choice.  Doesn't your hosting service offer LetsEncrypt certificates which are free?  If not and they refuse to, I would be shifting to somewhere that isn't trying to gouge for something that is readily available these days.